# C++ implementation

Tags: c++

I've read this line in a book:-
"When we ask the C++ implementation to run a program, it does so by calling this function."

And I'm wondering about what "C++ implementation" means or what it specifically is. Help!?

Comment: Would that be the `main` function, perchance?

Comment: Yes, it is the main function :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"C++ implementation" means the compiler plus linker plus standard libraries plus the system that the program actually runs on. Everything except your source, basically.

An *implementation* is something that *implements* the C++ standard.

So the book is not saying that any particular thing calls your function. Rather, that whole bundle, or some part(s) of it, will ensure that `main` is called.

In practice, this means that your compiled executable contains some system-specific startup code, followed by initializers for static objects, followed by a call to your main function.

Answer (score 0):

May be the c++ runtime library is the implementation in this case. The runtime library initializes static variables and does other stuff and finally calls main.